# Is there a plugin of jQuery can provide the editable & deletable dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

It meant I can edit/delete the options in the dropdownlist. Thanks.

Updates: May be should use DIV to provide the similar features?

Comment: Editable and deleteable by who?

Comment: @Shoban default dropdownlist can't edit/delete options, I want to be able to do these.

Comment: You want to design a dropdownlist for your form? for example asking user to select his country and list of countries should dropdown allowing user to select one among them?

Comment: @Cynial, please check my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It would be simple to make its options editable/deletable using just javascript without the need of creating a plugin just for this.

You can just add hyperlinks next to the dropdown for the 'edit' and 'delete' actions and add to them some javascript code like this:

```
$("a#editDropdown").click(function(){ 
  $("#inputEdit").val($("#dropdown option:selected").html());
  $("#dropdown").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $("#inputEdit, a#saveChanges").show();
});

$("a#saveChanges").click(function(){
  $("#dropdown option:selected").html($("#inputEdit"));
  $("#dropdown").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("#inputEdit, a#saveChanges").hide();
});

$("a#deleteDropdown").click(function(){
  $("#dropdown option:selected").remove();
});
```

And its corresponding html for this example:

```
<div>
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
    <option>opt3</option>
  </select>
  <a href="#" id="editDropdown">Edit</a>
  <a href="#" id="deleteDropdown">Delete</a>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="inputEdit" />
  <a href="#" id="saveChanges" style="display: none;">Save changes</a>
</div>
```

It works in my mind. I haven't tested it live yet but I hope you understand it.

Comment: Thanks, I know what you meant. I want to put the operations in the options. Anyway, It seems there are no such plugin so I need to do all the things.